# QTabWidget не отображаются данные

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qtabwidget

Я создавал программу на *PyQt5*. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы на заданном количестве вкладок в `QTabWidget` появились надписи.

Снизу я выделил часть кода, в которой происходят эти действия. Выводятся цифры только в последней вкладке, а в остальных ничего.

Я создал списки из `layout`, `label` и тд, и в цикле выводил их на экран. Потом надо будет выводить много элементов для этого `layout`.

Помогите, пожалуйста! Я провозился я с этой проблемой больше 3 часов, так и не придумав решения.

```
self.layoutsStats = []
self.layoutRow = QHBoxLayout()
self.rowLabels = [QLabel('1', self), QLabel('2', self), QLabel('3', self),
                          QLabel('4', self), QLabel('5', self)]
self.layoutRow.addStretch(1)
for i in self.rowLabels:
    self.layoutRow.addWidget(i)
self.layoutRows = []
self.layouts = []
self.scrolls = []
self.widgets = []
self.ws = []
self.layoutRows.append(self.layoutRow)
for i in range(len(rowTitles)):
    self.layoutRows.append(self.layoutRow)
    self.layouts.append(QVBoxLayout())
    self.layouts[i].addStretch(1)
    self.scrolls.append(QScrollArea())

    self.ws.append(QWidget())
    self.ws[i].setLayout(self.layoutRows[i])
    self.ws[i].resize(1118, 40)
    self.layouts[i].addWidget(self.ws[i])

    self.widgets.append(QWidget())
    self.widgets[i].setLayout(self.layouts[i])
    self.scrolls[i].setWidget(self.widgets[i])
    self.scrolls[i].resize(1121, 711)
    self.tabWidget.addTab(self.scrolls[i], rowTitles[i])
```

[image: Цифры выводятся обрезанными и только на последней вкладке, независимо от количества столбцов]

[image: На остальных вкладках просто пусто]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Класс `QTabWidget` предоставляет контейнер, состоящий из панели вкладок,
где каждая вкладка содержит область страницы, где мы можем разместить любой виджет.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.qtabwidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self) 
        
        widget = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit("QPlainTextEdit 1")
        label  = 'Tab &1'
        widget2 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit("QPlainTextEdit 2")
        
        # Мы можем добавить вкладки со значками в QTabWidget, используя метод 
        # QTabWidget.addTab(виджет QWidget *, const QIcon & icon, const QString & label). 
        # Виджет представляет виджет внутри вкладки. 
        # Значок представляет собой значок вкладки. метка представляет метку вкладки. 
        # Этот метод возвращает int с позицией вкладки внутри QTabWidget.
        
        tab_index1 = self.qtabwidget.addTab(widget, label)
        
        tab_index2 = self.qtabwidget.addTab(widget2, 'Tab &2')
        self.qtabwidget.setTabIcon(tab_index2, QtGui.QIcon('im.png'))
        self.qtabwidget.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32)) # Изменить размер значка вкладок
        
        self.qtabwidget.addTab(
                QtWidgets.QLabel("QLabel Tab &3", alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter), 
                QtGui.QIcon('Ok.png'),
                'Tab &3')
        
        # Не показывает 
        self.qtabwidget.addTab(None, "Без Виджета")
        
        #print(f"tab_index1={tab_index1}, tab_index2={tab_index2},\n qtabwidget.count={self.qtabwidget.count()}")

        # Мы можем закрыть вкладки QTabWidget, активировав свойство tabsClosable 
        # с помощью метода QTabWidget.setTabsClosable(bool closeable). 
        # Если значение closeable равно True, вкладки будут закрыты, 
        # а если значение False, они не смогут закрыться.
        
        self.qtabwidget.setTabsClosable(True)  
        # Необходимо подключить сигнал QTabWidget.tabCloseRequested() к соответствующему слоту.
        self.qtabwidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.qtabwidget_tabcloserequested)
        
        # Изменить форму вкладок QTabWidget
        # Мы можем изменить форму вкладок QTabWidget, используя метод 
        # QTabWidget.setTabShape(TabShape shape). 
        # shape представляет форму вкладок, по умолчанию форма вкладок QTabWidget.Rounded.
        #print(f"\n `tabShape` получает форму вкладок QTabWidget: {self.qtabwidget.tabShape()}")
        self.qtabwidget.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Triangular)
        #print(f" `tabShape` получает форму вкладок QTabWidget: {self.qtabwidget.tabShape()}")
        
        # Изменить положение вкладок QTabWidget
        #  с помощью метода QTabWidget.setTabPosition(TabPosition position). 
        #  position представляет позицию вкладок, по умолчанию позиция вкладок QTabWidget.North (Выше).
        # Получить положение вкладок QTabWidget, используя метод QTabWidget.tabPosition(). 
        # Этот метод возвращает TabPosition.(North  South  West   East)
        
        self.qtabwidget.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.East)  
        #print(f" `tabPosition` получает положение вкладок QTabWidget: {self.qtabwidget.tabPosition()}")

        # Включить и отключить вкладки QTabWidget
        # Мы можем включить или отключить вкладку QTabWidget, 
        # используя метод QTabWidget.setTabEnabled(int index, bool enable). 
        # index представляет индекс вкладки. 
        # Если enable - True, то активируется вкладка, а если False, то отключается.
        # Мы можем узнать, включена ли вкладка, используя метод QTabWidget.isTabEnabled(int index).
        
        self.qtabwidget.setTabEnabled(0, False) # отключить вкладку
        self.qtabwidget.setTabEnabled(1, True)  # включить вкладку 
        #print(f" `isTabEnabled` включена ли вкладка(index=0): {self.qtabwidget.isTabEnabled(0)}")
        #print(f" `isTabEnabled` включена ли вкладка(index=1): {self.qtabwidget.isTabEnabled(1)}")
        
        # Получить количество вкладок QTabWidget
        # Мы можем получить количество вкладок QTabWidget, используя метод QTabWidget.count(). 
        # Этот метод возвращает int.
        print(f"\n `count` Получить количество вкладок: {self.qtabwidget.count()}")

        # Издайте сигнал currentChanged из QTabWidget
        # Сигнал QTabWidget.currentChanged(int index) генерируется при изменении индекса страницы. 
        # index представляет новый индекс текущей страницы. 
        # индекс может быть -1, если в QTabWidget нет виджета. !
        
        self.qtabwidget.currentChanged.connect(self.qtabwidget_currentchanged)
        
        # Сигнал QTabWidget.tabCloseRequested(int index) выдается при нажатии кнопки закрытия вкладки. 
        # index представляет индекс вкладки.
        # Прежде чем мы должны активировать свойство tabsClosable QTabWidget, 
        # используя метод QTabWidget.setTabsClosable(bool enable). 
        # Если enable - True, вкладки могут быть закрыты, а если False, их нельзя закрыть.
        # self.qtabwidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.qtabwidget_tabcloserequested)
        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.qtabwidget)
        
    # В реализации слота мы удаляем вкладку, но сначала мы удаляем виджет, который он содержит.
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def qtabwidget_tabcloserequested(self, index):
        """ Удаляет вкладку с указанным индексом, 
            но сначала удаляет содержащийся в ней виджет. 
        """

        # gets the widget
        widget = self.qtabwidget.widget(index)

        # if the widget exists
        if widget:
            # removes the widget
            widget.deleteLater()

        # removes the tab of the QTabWidget
        self.qtabwidget.removeTab(index)
        print(f"\n Закрыли вкладку с ииндексои: {index}")
        
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def qtabwidget_currentchanged(self, index):
        print(f"\n Hовый индекс текущей страницы: {index}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setWindowTitle('QTabWidget')
    window.resize(400, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]