# Можно ли в PyQt сделать вкладки как в ttk.notebook?

Tags: python, pyqt5, tkinter, pyqt, ttk

Можно ли в PyQt5 сделать что то подобное как в Tkinter в ttk.notebook?
а если да то можно эти вкладки сделать вертикальными?

вот пример вкладок в tkinter:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мне нужно чтоб были такие же вкладки только в PyQt, и желательно вертикальные

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QTabWidget.html

Comment: Покажите изображение того что вы хотите получить. Ну и не забывайте показывать пример того что вы уже успели попробовать сделать.

Comment: @S.Nick уже обновил вопрос

Comment: Selasi какой из постов отвечает на ваш вопрос? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1159149/ , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1092931 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1094585 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1093109

Comment: все эти посты отвечают на мой вопрос